# Want Tableau Public to combine all columns together in one graph

Tags: tableau-api

I've added data to Tableau Public and made a large number of individual line graphs for different fields of education.

See screencap here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjfFK.png

I'm not sure how to put all these separate graphs together in one, or better yet to allow a user to pick and choose different fields of education to compare themselves (perhaps a check-box or drop-down menu).

Any ideas, or specific resources that provide appropriate advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen grab, it seems you need to organize / normalize your data first.

If the table is organized as

```
Record 1999 2000 2001
Rec1       10   20  30
Rec2       15   25  35
```

It would be best to reorganize the data first as

```
Record    Year FieldValue
Rec1      1999 10
Rec1      2000 20
....       .... ..
Rec2      2001 35
```

Then you should be able to achieve what you want.